# Custom listview for AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to have my AlertDialog with a custom list view but can't seem to get it to show or run without error.

```
   private void buildDialog(){

        int selectedItem = -1; //somehow get your previously selected choice
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(customView);
        builder.setTitle("Select Weapon").setCancelable(true);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(inventory, selectedItem, "Desc", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            { 
                ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                itemId = lv.getAdapter().getItemId(which);
                new changeEQ().execute();
            }
        });



        dialog = builder.create();
    }
```

This is my AlertDialog but can't figure out what to add to get my custom layouts, listview & listrow to be used. I've looked around at guides online but nothing they show seems to work for me. IE I must be doing something wrong.

EDIT: changed code to include answer but has no change on what is showed on screen. No errors yet no change in look.

Comment: could you please provide the Logcat output for the error you're getting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a custom layout that you want to pass to your AlertDialog try:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(customView);
```

If you want to define listeners try:

```
ListView list = (ListView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do as you please
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I need to take out setSingleChoiceItems and treat the alertDialog as if it was an activity listview?