# AlertDialog - DialogInterface onClick OR ListView onClick not Getting Called on Item Click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

**I WANT TO DISMISS ALERT DIALOG** on click of **ListView** Item which I have bind in Custom Array Adapter.

### onClick of DialogInterface OR OnItemClickListener of ListView not getting called on click of Item.

I have used following code to bind [this](https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/364710) API:

Getting Data:

```
RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitClient.getPinCodeApiService();
Call<List<PinCodeModel>> call = retrofitInterface.getAreaDetailsByPinCode(pinCode);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PinCodeModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<PinCodeModel>> call, Response<List<PinCodeModel>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            List<PinCodeModel> list = response.body();
            if (list != null) {
                PinCodeModel model = list.get(0);
                if (model.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(RetrofitClient.SUCCESS)) {
                    List<PostOffice> postOffices = model.getPostOffice();
                    if (postOffices.size() > 0) {
                        showAreaDialog(postOffices);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, model.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, model.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, getString(R.string.string_something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<PinCodeModel>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, getString(R.string.string_something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Crashlytics.logException(t);
        Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
```

Showing Dialog:

```
private void showAreaDialog(List<PostOffice> postOffices) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddMyBusinessActivity.this);

    ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    AreaAdapter areaAdapter = new AreaAdapter(this, postOffices);
    listView.setAdapter(areaAdapter);
    builderSingle.setTitle("Select Area");
    builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            PostOffice strName = postOffices.get(i);
            Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, strName.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builderSingle.setView(listView);
    alertDialog = builderSingle.show();
}
```

I have tried this one too:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new 
 AlertDialog.Builder(AddMyBusinessActivity.this);

    //ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    AreaAdapter areaAdapter = new AreaAdapter(this, postOffices);
    builderSingle.setAdapter(areaAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            PostOffice strName = postOffices.get(i);
            Toast.makeText(AddMyBusinessActivity.this, strName.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("TAG", "onItemClick: ");
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builderSingle.setTitle("Select Area");
    builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

[image]

I am clicking on any item but nothing happen. Can anyone please help me?

I HAVE TRIED ALL THE RELATED LINKS on **STACKOVERFLOW** but didn't get succeed.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368030/1318946
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44606815/1318946

I have also tried to make xml file with listview and inflate it to AlertDialog but now worked for me.

**Edited:**

Here is **row_layout_area.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/parentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_4sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/area_text_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Soham ERP Pvt. Ltd." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city_state_country"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/area_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/area_text_view"
                tools:text="Software, Software Company" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Are you getting toast on click of item?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your current issue, but did you know that `AlertDialog.Builder()` has the `setAdapter()` method, with which you can pass a `ListAdapter` without having to provide your own `ListView`?

Comment: `Toast` is not displaying that means Click Listener is not getting called

Comment: **onClick of DialogInterface OR OnItemClickListener of ListView not getting called on click of Item.** @Omi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with by removing or set to false

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
```

like

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/parentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_4sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Comment: Thank you @Omi, Its really very silly mistake but I missed it. Thank you for your time. I just removed that two lines.